# NodeJs findOneAndUpdate get modified columns

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to check which columns were modified or to trigger action when one column e.g 'nick' was updated? I am using Mongoose.

Comment: please add your db query which you are using to update

Answer (score 1):

In `findOneAndUpdate` there is a option called `new: boolean` which returns the new document rather than the old document.

From the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { name: 'jason bourne' }, {new: true}, callback)
```

Comment: How to know the Columns that were changed?